# How to write startup script for Systemd?

Tags: shell-script, systemd, init-script

I have 2 graphics cards on my laptop. One is IGP and another discrete.

I've written a shell script to to turn off the discrete graphics card.

How can I convert it to systemd script to run it at start-up?

Answer (score 412, accepted):

There are mainly two approaches to do that:

### With script

If you have to run a script, you don't convert it but rather run the script via a `systemd` service:

Therefore you need two files: the script and the `.service` file (unit configuration file).
Make sure your script is executable and the first line (the *shebang*) is `#!/bin/sh`. Then create the `.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system` (a plain text file, let's call it `vgaoff.service`).
For example:

1. the script: `/usr/bin/vgaoff`
2. the unit file: `/etc/systemd/system/vgaoff.service`

Now, edit the unit file. Its content depends on how your script works:

If `vgaoff` just powers off the gpu, e.g.:

```
exec blah-blah pwrOFF etc
```

then the content of `vgaoff.service` should be:

```
[Unit]
Description=Power-off gpu

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vgaoff

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If `vgaoff` is used to power off the GPU and also to power it back on, e.g.:

```
start() {
  exec blah-blah pwrOFF etc
}

stop() {
  exec blah-blah pwrON etc
}

case $1 in
  start|stop) "$1" ;;
esac
```

then the content of `vgaoff.service` should be:

```
[Unit]
Description=Power-off gpu

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vgaoff start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vgaoff stop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Without script

For the most trivial cases, you can do without the script and execute a certain command directly:

To power off:

```
[Unit]
Description=Power-off gpu

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo OFF > /whatever/vga_pwr_gadget/switch"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To power off and on:

```
[Unit]
Description=Power-off gpu

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo OFF > /whatever/vga_pwr_gadget/switch"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "echo ON > /whatever/vga_pwr_gadget/switch"
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Enable the service

Once you're done with the files, enable the service:

```
systemctl enable vgaoff.service
```

It will start automatically on next boot. You could even enable and start the service in one go with

```
systemctl enable --now vgaoff.service
```

as of `systemd v.220` (on older setups you'll have to start it manually).
For more details see [`systemd.service`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) manual page.

### Troubleshooting

- [How to see full log of a `systemd` service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/225401/22142)
- [`systemd` service exit codes and status information explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/458648/22142)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. The script contains one command "echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch"

Comment: it fails with following message  
vgaoff.service - Power-off gpu
          Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vgaoff.service; enabled)  
          Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue, 11 Sep 2012 23:46:46 +0530; 30s ago  
         Process: 5258 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/vgaoff (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)  
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/vgaoff.service

Comment: oops,not again, I missed this small thing, it is working fine.. thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and useful guide, but one command is IMHO dangerous: /bin/sh -c "echo OFF > /whatever/vga_pwr_gadget/switch" overwrites /whatever/vga_pwr_gadget/switch with the text "OFF". shouldn't it be & instead of >, which would be: /bin/sh -c "echo OFF & /whatever/vga_pwr_gadget/switch"? Or without the echo part at all? (that's the way I use it successfully.)

Comment: @don_crissti: at least I was foolish enough to overwrite my /sbin/hdparm file/program that way...   ...which wasn't too bad, it was easy getting the original back. But it could be a potential trap for users which aren't too CLI experienced like me or even less - then they won't get the original back. ;-)

Comment: @Bazon - according to this logic, thousands of answers on this site are "potential traps" for inexperienced users. People who don't know / fully understand what `echo SOMETHING > /some/file` does (or any other command as a matter of fact) should get familiar with the basics of CLI before attempting to run stuff on their systems. That aside, FYI, [read](http://tinyurl.com/btzljgd) how to switch dGPU off on several laptop models, see if the commands used there could be replaced with something like you suggest. Also, to restore the original file you usually reinstall the package that owns it.

Comment: @don_crissti Maybe you could comment on my new related question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224992/33386

Comment: Perfect answer! want more of these types!

Comment: On Ubuntu Xenial LTS I had to make sure that my init script had LSB header. Which is a block of code that starts with "### BEGIN INIT INFO" and ends with "### END INIT INFO". Otherwise, systemctl enable would fail. You can see an example of such LSB header in almost any init script under /etc/init.d/ on Ubuntu Xenial LTS.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow - no, [that's for service files from upstream](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224992)

Comment: @don_crissti whoops! thanks for the tip. (deleted my original comment to avoid propagation of misleading information.)

Comment: DO NOT install your script into init.d for the old systemV and then call this script from a mydaemon.service file. This will break horrible. I learned something today

Comment: For more information on .service files and how to customize one for your needs, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu 16 and when you do  `sudo systemctl enable ...` it reports `Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links`, you may need to put the file in `/lib/systemd/system/` instead of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` before running that `enabe` command.  Also, make sure to delete the file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` if you did so.  Anyways, that's what worked for me.

Comment: When doing redirection using E.G. `> file.out  2>&1 &` inside your `/usr/bin/vgaoff` file, then this must be moved to the end of the `ExecStart` line of `/etc/systemd/system/vgaoff.service` instead, otherwise it will hang when you run `systemctl start vgaoff` - see also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004853/systemd-is-hanging-when-i-start-or-restart-a-service

Answer (score 4):

Adding startup items in systemd is complex and cumbersome. To make this more convenient, I have wirte a tool [add_service](https://github.com/DIYer22/add_service) which provides a simple way to quickly add startup item in systemd.

Install:

```
pip3 install add_service
```

Usage:

```
python -m add_service [shell_file/cmd] [user (default `whoami`)]
```

Examples:

```bsh
python -m add_service ssh_nat.sh  # by default user is `whoami`
python -m add_service "`which python3` -m http.server 80" root
```