# Simplest way to run a script on startup (or reboot/shutdown) but only if it has not already been executed today?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

What's the simplest way you know? Using any tool

Comment: Please define `today`. Is that `less than 24 hours`, or `same date as today`, or something else?

Comment: @Seamus Same date

Answer (score 10):

In the beginning of your script, just touch a flag somewhere, so that subsequent invocations of that script can check for the existence and age of that flag.

There's some ambiguity in your question. So first, let's assume that you're asking "How to make a script execute only if certain amount of time has passed since the last time the script executed."

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
flag="/var/tmp/$(basename -- $0).flag"
min_age=$(( 60 * 60 * 24 )) # 24 hours

if [ -e "$flag" ] ;then
  (( $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r "$flag") > min_age )) || exit 1
fi
touch "$flag"

# Proceed with your script
# ...
```

But if you're asking "How to make a script execute only if it has not already been executed since midnight"...

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
flag="/var/tmp/$(basename -- $0).flag"

if [ -e "$flag" ] ;then
  [ $(date +%F) = $(date +%F -r "$flag") ] && exit 1
fi
touch "$flag"

# Proceed with your script
# ...
```

--

And if you're simply asking "How to run a sctipt at shutdown" -- then that varies widely from distro to distro. You'll most likely need to look into `/etc/rc6.d`. On my system, for example, I have `/etc/rc.d/rc.local_shutdown`, where I can add stuff. You'll need to mention what distro you're using.

Or check out this thread...
[Execute a command before shutdown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/execute-a-command-before-shutdown)

Comment: better to use /var/tmp instead of /tmp.  in short: /var/tmp survives reboots, /tmp doesn't.  see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/what-is-the-difference-between-tmp-and for details and caveats.

Comment: You forgot about `run a script on startup (or reboot/shutdown)`

Comment: @Hannu Not really. He can run it at startup, or shutdown, or any time he wants, or as many times he wants, but the script will actually execute only if more than 24 hours have passed since the last time it successfully executed.

Comment: Ahh... ;-) the word `automatically` not included in the Q. Sorry.

Comment: It might be more flexible to have the script take the timestamp file name (and maybe the time interval) as an explicit argument, and then exit with 0 or 1 depending on if the condition is met or not. So that you could then run `.../shouldrun.sh /var/tmp/timestamp-for-thing-x 86400 && .../run-thing-x.sh`. But of course it works for a one-use even without that.

Comment: Also note that this checks if the work was done within the last 24 h period, not "today". With GNU tools you could relatively easily check for "today" with something like `today=$(date +%F); ts=$(cat tsfile); [[ $ts < $today ]] && echo $today > tsfile && run some stuff` (note it's string comparison, and I didn't test actually)

Comment: Ah, hmm, `EPOCHSECONDS` is Bash 5.0+ only. Older systems may still have 4.x, so may need `$(date +%s)` instead. (I'll stop now.)

Comment: @Pourko, yep. Depends on what they're actually doing.

Comment: @Pourko, is it five years already? Hmm, no, it's just two years, from 2019-01. 4.4. is a bit less than five years. Now, I did check that even Debian stable has 5.0, as well as the latest Ubuntu LTS, but the previous ones don't. Anyway, it's not too long ago someone pointed out to me that some RHEL/CentOS that's still supported only has Bash 4.2 by default, so that's why it came to mind.

Comment: @cas `/var/tmp` is not guaranteed to survive reboots either, though it’s admittedly more likely than `/tmp`. The best option is probably somewhere under `/var/cache` or `/var/lib` (`/var/lock` would be the logical place, but on most modern systems it’s a symlink to `/run/lock`, and therefore will not survive a reboot).

Comment: @Hannu Yes I want it to run automatically! Sorry for all the ambiguities. I don't know how to run something on shutdown, I thought it would be very useful for me, but not sure if it's common.

Comment: I use Fedora. Right now Fedora 33

Answer (score 5):

*Simplest* is largely a matter of *opinion*, but I feel the simplest way to do this is to use `cron`. You will need some other "ingredients" to accomplish your objective, but `cron` can serve as the scheduler for starting a script at `boot` time. This assumes the version of `cron` on your system offers the `@reboot` facility; see `man 5 crontab` to verify the "special" strings are allowed (`@reboot`, `@yearly`, etc).

That said, using `cron` is as simple as editing your user's `crontab`. From your `bash` command line:

```bsh
$ crontab -e
```

This will open your `crontab` in your default editor. Add the following line:

```
@reboot sleep 15; /path/to/your/script >> /path/to/your/iofile.txt 2>&1
```

This runs your script each time your system boots.

- Since `cron` doesn't know the status of any services required in your script, the `sleep 15` command is used to give the OS 15 seconds to marshal all required system resources. You may need more or less than this, depending on the resources needed, and other variables.
- Use full path specifications in your `crontab` as the *environment* (in particular the `PATH`) is different than in your interactive shell.
- Script output that would go to `stderr` or `stdout` should be *re-directed* to a local file (*iofile.txt* here). The *iofile.txt* file will provide an easy way to access any errors thrown by your script - very helpful for debugging!

You have asked that a condition be applied to running your script `@reboot`: **"but only if it has not already been executed today"** . This is taken to mean that there is a ***possibility that the script may have been executed manually by a user***, or that the system may have been re-booted previously in the same day.

Meeting that condition of course depends on your definition of ***"today"***; i.e. "today" as in the past 24 hours, or "today" as in on this same date.

#### For the case that **`today=24 hours or less`**, your condition may be satisfied as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
LAST_BOOT=$(cat /path/to/your/timestamp.txt)
CURRENT_BOOT=$(date +%s)
ELAPSED_TIME=$((CURRENT_BOOT - LAST_BOOT))
echo $CURRENT_BOOT > /path/to/your/timestamp.txt
# test ELAPSED_TIME < threshold
if [ $((ELAPSED_TIME <= 86400)) ]; then exit; fi

# the balance of your script follows...
```

Note use of the `+%s` format for `date` gives the epoch time; this allows us to *subtract* the two boot times to check for 24 hours (86,400 seconds).

#### For the case that **`today=same date`**, your condition may be satisfied as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
LAST_BOOT=$(cat /path/to/your/timestamp.txt)
CURRENT_BOOT=$(date +%d)
# test for same date
if [ $((CURRENT_BOOT = LAST_BOOT)) ]; then exit; fi 

# the balance of your script follows...
```

Note the `date +%d` format provides the date only. We test for equality between the last boot time, and the current time in the `if` statement which means that the script has already been run on this date.

#### Alternatively:

After considering all of your comments just now, you may wish to consider `anacron`. It's not in as wide use as `cron`, but it does have the advantage that its `@daily` schedule *"will move tasks to different moments so they are run when the system is on"*. You may also wish to compare its [advantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron#Advantages), and its [disadvantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron#Disadvantages) compared to `cron`. If you wish to dig deeper, [this may help](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cron+vs+anacron&t=ffnt&ia=web)

Comment: I don't thinmk the OP was so much asking about how to run a script on startup, rather than how to prevent it from running too often.

Comment: @patilan: You ***may*** be correct, but if the question is taken at "face value", I have to say it certainly ***seems*** that's what he's asking. But then again, he is a "Physics Enthusiast" - not necessarily an "English Enthusiast"  :)

Comment: @patilan Correct!

Comment: So @reboot means at startup? I thought it typically meant resetting (like a shutdown but the pc doesn't shutdown and starts again). Is there a `@keyword` to indicate I want it on every kind of shutdown? (either reset or actual shutdown).

Comment: @PhysicsEnthusiast123: Yeah - typically it does. `@reboot` means anytime the system is started - either from issuing a `reboot` at the console/CLI, or the system has been powered down & you start it up. There is no `@shutdown` keyword. Your questions suggest that I've wasted a lot of time trying to answer the question you asked instead of the one you meant to ask... what do you think???

Comment: @Seamus Your answer is awesome, I learned things and I'm grateful, thanks! I'm thinking 24hs might be better than "today". You and the others guys gave me a lot to think and research. Not sure which answer to accept yet, sorry

Answer (score 4):

You could consider using [anacron](https://man.cx/?page=anacron).

Anacron allows scheduling periodic jobs on computers that are not turned on all the time. To achieve this, it maintains so-called timestamp files that record the last time a job was run. When the computer is on, anacron regularly gets triggered via various mechanisms (startup script, regular cron jobs, systemd timers) and kicks off jobs that are due based on the timestamp files.

With anacron, in order to run a command once per day, you need to put a line like this into `/etc/anacrontab`:

```
@daily  0   daily-job   command
```

- The first field is the frequency and can be `@daily`, `@weekly` or
  `@monthly` as well as an arbitrary number of days (e.g., `2` for
  every 2 days).
- The second field is the delay to start running the job after anacron
  gets triggered.
- The third field is the name of the job.
- Finally, the fourth field is the command to execute.

On Debian derivatives, you can drop a script into `/etc/cron.daily` instead, since anacron (if installed) takes over the task of running daily, weekly and monthly cron jobs by default.

Another option is [fcron](http://fcron.free.fr/), which allows doing the same (and possibly more), but I do not have personal experience with it.

Comment: Oh wow never heard of those, and sounds like I need because my problem is precisely that the pc isn't always turned on, so I was thinking running it on shutdown could be very useful for me. I'll have to research those. Thanks!

Comment: @Seamus I made the question because I was having a hard time finding a way to run cronjobs in a pc that isn't always turned on. I was already thinking Linux assumes everything is a server running 24/7. That's why I thought maybe the answer was to run on startup/shutdown instead. That might have hinted Zoltan my pc wasn't always on. I'm not sure if anacron/fcron will be what I end up using, but at least now I know they exist (could be useful some day if not today).

Comment: @PhysicsEnthusiast123: That clarification in your OP would have helped your question. I **may** have a better grasp of it now, and yes, `anacron` may be better-suited to your use case - [Wikipedia has a good article summarizing `anacron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron). The only advantage that `cron` may offer is that it's pre-installed on virtually every Linux distro - `anacron` will probably need to be added.