# davmail systemd launcher on headless server

Tags: arch-linux, init-script

I'm trying to follow the ArchWiki guide for writing a [custom service file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_custom_.service_files) to launch [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net) as a system-wide daemon. Previously I had a line in my ~/.xinitrc that read

```
nohup /usr/bin/davmail /etc/conf.d/davmail.properties
```

as per the DavMail instructions (where `/usr/bin/davmail` is a symlink to `/usr/share/java/davmail/davmail.sh`). Now that I've made the computer into a headless server, I'd like the auto-launcher to be independent of an X session.

All the guides I've seen online for a DavMail initscript assume that the distro is using sysvinit, not systemd. My attempt at a custom systemd service file is

```
[Unit]
Description=DavMail Exchange Gateway
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/davmail /etc/conf.d/davmail.properties
ExecStop=killall davmail

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which fails to fork properly. Prepending the `ExecStart` command with `/usr/bin/nohup` is no help, because systemd complains about an invalid argument (preferring to take control of the daemonization itself, if I'm correctly understanding previous forum answers). Changing the Service Type to `oneshot` or `simple` also fails.

I think an issue here is that DavMail requires a Java interpreter to run, and systemd service files aren't as flexible as shell scripts in handing off the job to a Java interpreter. But maybe there's a much simpler explanation. Has anyone successfully written a systemd service file for DavMail that they'd be willing to share?

Comment: Following the steps in [don_crissti's answer to a related query](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd?rq=1), I wrote a systemd service file that calls a shell script in `/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/` , and now the DavMail daemon will launch without any problems.

Comment: If it's working, please feel free to post the script for other people!

Answer (score 4):

You must define it as a simple service (the forking is for process that finishes when the daemon is already started). For it's working like a charm in Arch

```
[Unit]
Description=DavMail Exchange Gateway
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/davmail /etc/conf.d/davmail.properties
ExecStop=killall davmail

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that don't have a debian or a distro based on it and downloaded the generic Linux (other) package (that includes the davmail.sh), the following worked for me:

```
[Unit]
Description=DavMail Exchange Gateway
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/opt/davmail/davmail.pid
ExecStart=/opt/davmail/davmail.sh /opt/davmail/davmail.properties

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of experimentation, I found a somewhat-more-optimal 
solution for using Davmail with the `davmail.server=true` directive, assuming you have performed a manual install.

```
[Unit]  
Description=DavMail Exchange Gateway  
Requires=network.target  
After=network.target  

[Service]  
Type=simple  
RemainAfterExit=no  
GuessMainPid=yes  
Environment=BASE=<< YOUR_MANUAL_INSTALL_PATH_HERE >>  
Environment=PROPERTIES=<< PATH_TO_davmail.properties >>
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c "for i in ${BASE}/lib/*; do /usr/bin/systemctl set-environment CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:$i ; done"  
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/davmail_errors.log -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=60 -cp ${BASE}/davmail.jar:${CLASSPATH} davmail.DavGateway ${PROPERTIES}  
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP ${MAINPID}  
ExecStop=/bin/kill -QUIT ${MAINPID}  
Restart=always  
RestartSec=3  

[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For those who have done packaged installs, they can likely comment out the "ExecStartPre" line, and then set BASE=/usr/share/java and PROPERTIES=/etc/davmail.properties .

Reasons this is "nicer" include showing the java process console output in your default syslog location ( `/var/log/syslog` || `/var/log/messages` || wherever ), making it easier to debug when it goes bad.