# Running a script during booting/startup; init.d vs cron @reboot

Tags: scripting, cron, startup, init-script, sysvinit

I am currently trying to understand the difference between `init.d` and cron `@reboot` for running a script at startup/booting of the system.

The use of `@reboot` (this method was mentioned in [this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root) by *hs.chandra*) is some what simpler, by simply going into `crontab -e` and creating a `@reboot /some_directory/to_your/script/your_script.txt` and then `your_script.txt` shall be executed every time the system is rebooted. An in depth explanation of `@reboot` is [here](http://www.unixdaemon.net/linux/how-does-cron-reboot-work.html)

Alternatively by embedding `/etc/init.d/your_script.txt` into the *second line* of your script ie:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/your_script.txt
```

You can run `chmod +x /etc/init.d/your_script.txt` and that should also result for `your_script.txt` to run every time the system is booted.

1. What are the key differences between the two?
2. Which is more robust?
3. Is there a better one out of the two?
4. Is this the correct way of embedding a script to run during booting?

I will be incorporating a bash .sh file to run during startup.

Comment: Also relevant is systemd, [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd) [link2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**`init.d`**, also known as SysV script, is meant to start and stop services during system initialization and shutdown. (`/etc/init.d/` scripts are also run on systemd enabled systems for compatibility).

- The script is executed during the boot and shutdown (by default).
- The script should be an init.d script, not just a script . It should support `start` and `stop` and more (see [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-sysvinit))
- The script can be executed **during** the system boot (you can define when).

**`crontab`** (and therefore `@reboot`).

- cron will execute any regular command or script, nothing special here.
- any user can add a `@reboot` script (not just root)
- on a Debian system with systemd: cron's  @reboot is executed during `multi-user.target`.
- on a Debian system with SysV (not systemd), crontab(5) mention: *Please note that startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, is the time when the  cron(8)  daemon  startup.   In particular, it may be before some system daemons, or other facilities, were startup.  This is due to the boot order sequence of the machine.*
- it's easy to schedule the same script at boot and periodically.

**`/etc/rc.local`** is often considered to be ugly or deprecated (at least by [redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=734268)), still it had some nice features:

- rc.local will execute any regular command or script, nothing special here.
- on a Debian system with SysV (not systemd): `rc.local` was (almost) the last service to start.
- but on a Debian system with systemd: `rc.local` is executed after `network.target` by default (not `network-online.target` !)

Regarding systemd's `network.target` and `network-online.target`, read [Running Services After the Network is up](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/).

Comment: In my Ununtu 16.04, I need to remove `/var/run/crond.reboot` file each time, if I want than @reboot cron jobs are executed every time the sistem starts up. If this file existis @reboot cron jobs won't be executed

Comment: @Albert-Catala submit a bug to Ubuntu!

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, a clarification is in order:

- **init.d** is the directory that stores services control scripts, which control the starting and stopping of services such as `httpd` or `cron`
- **rc.local** is a service that allows running of arbitrary scripts as part of the system startup process

In terms of whether its better to use `rc.local` or `cron` to run your script, I suspect that it is more a question of aesthetics more than practicality. `cron`, as a task scheduler, is intended as a method to perform maintenance or upkeep to a machine, such as checking updates, cleaning caches, or performing security audits. This doesn't mean that it is limited to performing those functions, as it can run any script or command desired at the specified time (such as `@reboot`).

Using `rc.local`, on the other hand, would fall more within a system configuration type of task, as `rc.local`, being executed by the machines init system, is typically responsible for setting the machines network configuration, services or environments (but again, is not limited to just this task).

Both of these points, however, should be tempered by the fact that not all init systems offer an `rc.local` mechanism, and not all cron daemons offer an `@reboot` psuedo tag.

## Bonus Points

As mentioned, `init.d` is the directory that contains the scripts that control services that can be started or stopped on your system (at least on machines that use a `SysV` type init system). Depending on your init system and the purpose of your script, it may be reasonable to convert your script into an *init script* to be run in the same manner as a service. This, however, is heavily dependent on your init system as the framework surrounding how these files are constructed can differ greatly.

## Last Word

It should also be noted that typically bash scripts end with a suffix of `.sh` rather than `.txt`, as this immediately denotes the file is a shell script instead of a text file. That being said, provided it either has a *shebang* (`#!/bin/bash`) at the top of the file, or is called as `bash /path/to/script.whatever`, it shouldn't matter in terms of executing the script.

Comment: `bash` scripts typically do not *(and arguably should not)* end with an `sh` extension.

Comment: @mikeserv: While I agree that most bash scripts do not (and arguably should not) have any extension, usually files with the ".sh" extension are bash scripts -- see ["What's a .sh file?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805295/whats-a-sh-file) .

Comment: @DavidCary - that doesn't seem like a very authoritative source.

Comment: [Wikipedia: "list of filename extensions"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_list_of_filename_extensions_(S%E2%80%93Z)) and [Wikipedia: "shell script"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script#Life_cycle) also mention the surprisingly common ".sh" extension, with references.

Comment: "_typically bash scripts end with a suffix of `.sh` rather than `.txt`_" - specifically meaning `sh` is more accurate as a file name extension for bash scripts (or other shell scripts) than `txt` which typically denotes plain-text. You can use whatever extension makes you giggle, but common convention would be, if using an extension `sh` would be more appropriate and is commonly used; though it isn't required, especially for scripts that are intended to be executed from the `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

I am writing my answer below ;

> 1. What is the key differences between the two?

Apart from the differences mentioned by other users above, I would like to highlight the point that @reboot is dependent on crond daemon.
You are dependent on the order in which crond starts.
Although most of the cases, crond starts fine but it may fail sometime to start (atleast I have seen some failures in some of my projects).
When you write an init script, failure would typically occur if you do something wrong in  your script (an ex: relying on a service that will start after your service)

> 2. Which is more robust?

Based on above, I think that init is more robust. But there is another point as mentioned by "Franklin Piat" in the first answer. Usually you need init script for a daemon and you should follow the policy

> 3. Is there a better one out of the two?

I do not think so (rc.local is little bit old and deprecated)

> 4. Is this the correct way of embedding a script to run during booting?

Yes. Usually application/package writers do in this way.