# Where do I put my systemd unit file?

Tags: systemd, directory-structure

I [read](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) that there are two folders for unit files (not in user mode).

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/: units provided by installed packages
/etc/systemd/system/: units installed by the system administrator
```

Conflicting with this understanding is the answer to this question: [How to write startup script for Systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47715/33386). Can someone fill in the missing information so that I understand what is going on? (**UPDATE: The answer has been updated, and my understanding no longer conflicts with it.**)

Also, it seems that the scripts are organized in subfolders within the `/etc/systemd/system/` folder:

```
getty.target.wants
multi-user.target.wants
```

In another location I read that there are other locations. It seems these are for user-specific services.

```
/usr/lib/systemd/user/ where services provided by installed packages go.
/etc/systemd/user/ where system-wide user services are placed by the system administrator.
~/.config/systemd/user/ where the user puts its own services.
```

---

Update 2015-08-31:

For the sake of others, here is a link to a related question I recently asked: [Where do I put scripts executed by systemd units?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226535/where-should-scripts-be-placed-that-are-automatically-executed-by-systemd)

Comment: `/etc/systemd/system` is where *you* put your scripts, *pacman* puts package scripts in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` and issuing `systemctl enable foo.service` creates symlinks from `/usr` to `/etc`...

Comment: See `man systemd.target`: it explains the reasoning behind the groupings.

Comment: Aside from file locations, it's important to note that "user" services in systemd run only while a user is logged in. If you want a service to run all the time, it needs to be a "system" service, not a "user" one.

Comment: @MattRyall Wrong. A user service can be started at boot time if you do `loginctl enable-linger` ([ref](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances)).

Comment: Good to know, @user98761. I don't yet have enough karma to edit my comment, so will try to update later.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

**The best place to put *system* unit files:** `/etc/systemd/system`
Just be sure to add a target under the [Install] section, read "How does it know?" for details.  *UPDATE*: `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system` is another option, read "Gray Area" for details."

**The best place to put *user* unit files:** `/etc/systemd/user` or `$HOME/.config/systemd/user`
but it depends on permissions and the situation. Note also that user services will only run while a user session is active.

The truth is that systemd units (or as the intro sentence calls them, "unit configurations") can go **anywhere**—provided you are willing to make manual symlinks and you are aware of the caveats. It makes life easier to put the unit where `systemctl daemon-reload` can find it for some good reasons:

- Using a standard location means that systemd generators will find them and make them easy to enable at boot with `systemctl enable`. This is because your unit will automatically be added to a unit dependency tree (a unit cache).
- You do not need to think about permissions, because only the right privileged users can write to the designated areas.

## How does it know?

And how exactly does `systemctl enable` know where to create the symlink? You hard code it within the
unit itself under the `[install]` section. Usually there is a line like

```
[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

that corresponds to a predefined place on the filesystem.
This way, `systemctl` knows that this unit is dependent on a group of unit files called `multi-user.target` ("target" is the term used to designate unit dependency groups. You can list all groups with `systemctl list-units --type target`). The group of unit files to be loaded with a target is put in a `targetname.target.wants` directory. This is just a directory full of symlinks (or the real thing). If your `[Install]` section says it is `WantedBy` the `multi-user.target`, but if a symlink to it does not exist in the `multi-user.target.wants` directory, then it will not load. When the systemd unit generators add your unit file to the dependency tree cache at boot (you can manually trigger generators with `systemctl daemon-reload`), it automatically knows where to put the symlink—in this case in the directory `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` should you enable it.

## Key Points in the Manual:

> Additional units might be loaded into systemd ("linked") from
> directories not on the unit load path. See the link command for
> systemctl(1).

Under systemctl, look for *Unit File Commands*

### Unit File Load Path

Please read and understand the first sentence in the following quote from `man systemd.unit` (because it implies that all of the paths I mention here may not apply to you if your systemd was compiled with different paths):

> Unit files are loaded from a set of paths determined during compilation, described in the two tables below. Unit files found in directories listed earlier override files with the same name in directories lower in the list.

> When the variable `$SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` is set, the contents of this variable overrides the unit load path. If `$SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` ends with an empty component (":"), the usual unit load path will be appended to the contents of the variable.

Table 1 and Table 2 from `man systemd.unit` are good.

### Load paths when running in system mode (`--system`).

- `/etc/systemd/system` Local configuration
- `/run/systemd/system` Runtime units
- `/usr/lib/systemd/system` Units of installed packages (or `/lib/systemd/system` in some cases, read `man systemd.unit`)

### Load path when running in user mode (`--user`)

There is a difference between *per user* units and *all/global* users units.

#### User-dependent

- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/systemd/user`  User configuration (only used when `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set)
- `$HOME/.config/systemd/user`  User configuration (only used when `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set)
- `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/user`  Runtime units (only used when `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is set)
- `$XDG_DATA_HOME/systemd/user`  Units of packages that have been installed in the home directory (only used when `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is set)
- `$HOME/.local/share/systemd/user`  Units of packages that have been installed in the home directory (only used when `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is not set)

#### `--global` (all users)

Units that apply to all users--meaning owned by each user, too. So each user can stop these services even if an administrator enables them at boot.

- `/etc/systemd/user`  Local configuration for all users (`systemctl --global enable userunit.service`)
- `/usr/lib/systemd/user`  Units of packages that have been installed system-wide for all users (or `/lib/systemd/system` in some cases, read man systemd.unit)
- `/run/systemd/user`  Runtime units

## Gray Area

On the one hand, the [File Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/) (also `man file-hierarchy`) specifies that `/etc` is for local configurations that do not execute binaries. On the other hand
it specifies that `/usr/local/` "is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally". You could also argue (if not just for the purpose of organization) that all system unit files should go under `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system`, but this is intended for unit files that are part of "software" not from a package manager.
The corresponding systemd user units that are system-wide could go under
`/usr/local/lib/systemd/user`.

## Transient Unit

Another forgotten place is nowhere at all! Perhaps a lesser-known program is `systemd-run`. You can use it to run transient units on the fly. see `man systemd-run`.

For example, to schedule a reboot tomorrow morning at 4 a.m. (you might need `--force` to ensure a reboot happens):

```
systemd-run -u restart --description="Restarts machine" --on-calendar="2020-12-18 04:00:00" systemctl --force reboot
```

This will yield a transient unit file `restart.service` and a corresponding timer (because of the `--on-calendar`, (and indicated by `transient=yes` in the resulting transient unit definition).

`/run/systemd/transient/restart.service`

```
# This is a transient unit file, created programmatically via the systemd API. Do not edit.
[Unit]
Description=Restarts machine

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart="/usr/bin/systemctl" "--force" "reboot"
```

Note that there is also the more dangerous double force option `--force --force`, which tells the kernel to halt immediately (and, if you do not know what you're doing, unsafely, because it is almost equivalent to cutting the power).

Comment: The advice about putting unit files in `/etc/systemd/system`, is that general advice for self created unit files? Anything installed by a package manager should always put them in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` for eg.

Comment: @slm Yes, when the question refers to **my** systemd unit files, it is intended to imply self-created ones.

Comment: I would distinct: `/etc/systemd/user` for (guaranteed) system wide user services and `~/.config/systemd/user` for custom user specific services.

Comment: @JonathanKomar You should add `/lib/systemd/system` in your post, each time you mention `/usr/lib/systemd/system`. On many systems (notably on Ubuntu), this is the correct location.

Comment: @Atralb May I suggest you run `file /lib`? I do not use Ubuntu, but I would venture to guess that you'll see that it is indeed a symbolic link to `usr/lib`.

Comment: Nope => `file /lib` returns `/lib: directory`. `/usr/lib/systemd` doesn't even have a child directory called `system`. Moreover, here is an [excerpt](https://postimg.cc/87h5gRfH) of the `systemd.unit` manpage specifically referencing the folder. And another [excerpt2](https://postimg.cc/7bDjKgq4) from `man systemd` which also mentions the folder. The other folder mentioned `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system` doesn't exist either. Finally, the command `pkg-config systemd --variable=systemdsystemunitdir` ,which is the one packages should check to put their unit files, returns `/lib/systemd/system`.

Comment: @Atralb Ok, good to know, and thanks for identifying that. I would point out, however, that I specifically mention that you should read the man page systemd.unit. This is because the paths are compiler-option dependent (which indirectly depends on the OS you are using). This means that my post could potentially contain too much superfluous information, should I attempt to include every deviation. In this case, I'll add it, but future path deviations are going to be up to the reader to look up for himself/herself.

Comment: This answer is a great example of self-directed learning!

Comment: Is there a command, which could show all current load paths?

Comment: @EugenKonkov Seems less like a comment and more like a new question. Push “Ask Question” and shoot.

Answer (score 34):

`/etc/systemd/system` is where you put *your* scripts, pacman puts *package* scripts in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`.

Issuing `systemctl enable foo.service` creates symlinks from `/usr` to `/etc`. See the Unit Load Path section of `man systemd.unit(5)` for more detail.

Comment: This answer is more easy to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to know all the places where systemd will look for unit files, the following commands should be helpful.

Using [`systemd-analyze`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html#) command:

**All folders which can contain *user* services:**

*These are the places where you can put your own per-user configs*

```
systemd-analyze --user unit-paths
```

For administrative users, you may prefer putting your configs in the following folders (these will affect all users):

```
systemd-analyze --global unit-paths
```

**All folders which can contain *system* services:**

*These will most likely contain installed services from a package manager and will affect the system as a whole*

```
systemd-analyze --system unit-paths
```

See: [manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20File%20Load%20Path)

Comment: Does not work on CentOS 7.

Comment: @ceving: `unit-paths` "verb" of `systemd-analyze`, as well as its `--global` switch, were added in [Systemd v238](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/31a5924ed8627d0f774e8d5574129a796544bf4e), so not available in CentOS 7 or Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

One noticeable difference between /etc/systemd/system and /lib/systemd/system on Debian/Ubuntu system is, the service files under /lib/systemd/system can be masked while those under /etc/systemd/system cannot.  For example,

```
# ls /lib/systemd/system/mytest.service
# systemctl mask mytest
# ls /etc/systemd/system/mytest2.service
# systemctl mask mytest2
Failed to mask unit: File /etc/systemd/system/mytest2.service already exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written 3, one for `ntpd`, one for a second, static ethernet card, and one for running `p0f`, the passive OS identifer.  I put them all in `/etc/systemd/system`.  Looks like I could maybe let `systemd` handle the NTP stuff, but I don't think I want to rely on it that much.

Answer (score 0):

#### Search Paths

There are many places `systemd` looks for when you do `systemctl enable <unit-name>`. Regardless of where they are found, they will be symbolically linked to somewhere inside `/etc/systemd`.

You can consult the `man systemd.unit(5)` for a complete list, or use the `systemd-analyze` commands as noted in other answers. You can put your unit files in any of these locations. but you must pay attention to `precedence` and the `scope`.

`Precedence` as in which folders will be preferred by systemd if a unit file was found with the same name.

`Scope` as in user, global, and system.

#### Selecting a Folder

For instance, if you put your unit files to `~/.config/systemd/user.control`, then you would need to enable them with `systemctl enable --user <unit-file>`.

Usually, the unit files are for services, and services are usually for the host. So, I mostly just put custom units into `/etc/systemd/system` which is the system scope, and has precedence over anything and everything in case there is a name conflict.

```
pkg-config systemd --variable=systemdsystemconfdir
pkg-config systemd --variable=systemduserunitdir
pkg-config systemd --variable=systemduserconfdir
```

On my system, these returned in order:

```
/etc/systemd/system
/usr/lib/systemd/user
/etc/systemd/user
```