# Where do I put my systemd service?

Tags: systemd, directory

I've read several sources so far. Here are the three options I have encountered:

```
/etc/systemd/system

/usr/lib/systemd/system

/lib/systemd/system
```

I was originally putting my service in /lib/systemd/system, and it seems a bunch of other services are in that directory as well. However, it's supposed to be in /etc/systemd/system?? This source never talks about the third option: [Where do I put my systemd unit file on Arch Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224992/where-do-i-put-my-systemd-unit-file-on-arch-linux)

Also, this tutorial seems to put it in that directory. http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/

Please help clarify for me. Enabling my unit is leading to an error message: "Failed to enable unit: Invalid argument" I hypothesize because the directory is wrong. (I am using Arch Linux)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use Systemd services to launch "kiosk"-style Pi (running CentOS) systems. Systemd pulls from a few configuration directories, but generally you should put Systemd services in `/etc/systemd/system/`

There are, of course, some requirements of what must be contained in the service file, but as long as it's in that directory, a `sudo systemctl enable foo.service` enables that service. If you put your services in that directory and are still encountering errors, check your service file. It should contain at least:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sample Script Startup

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/valid/path/to/an/executable/file

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `Type` and `WantedBy` attributes may vary, depending on what you're trying to achieve, so read the [docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-managing_services_with_systemd#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files)!

Comment: ah ok thanks. So for the After = ... should I spell out the full directory since these services will be in different directories?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to do that. ``After`` should understand target names (bar.target) and should not need full paths.