# What is the "proper way" with to create a systemd service on a mounted (not booted) system?

Tags: systemd

There are lots of instructions out there for [creating basic systemd service files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74623/9745), but they all seem (rightfully so) to instruct you to make calls to `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl enable`. If you need to add a service to a drive you have mounted but not booted (think system orchestration), how would you do that purely by writing to the file system (files, directories, symlinks).

I'm sure there will be a few "it depends on where your X lives" and that is okay. This can have limited (or no) portability. I just want to make sure that my plan works.

That plan being:

1. Write a service file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`
2. Symlink to it from `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`

Comment: Related reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224992/135943

Answer (score 2):

What you're suggesting is essentially how `systemctl enable` works: it looks in the `[Install]` section of the service file and adds a symlink to the appropriate `.target.wants` directory indicated by `WantedBy=`. According to [the `systemd.unit` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), there are a few other directives that you need to look at to duplicate how `systemctl` does it:

- `Alias=` creates a symlink in the same directory as the unit
- `RequiredBy=` creates a symlink in the appropriate `.target.requires` directory
- `Also=` installs related units (look at each of those for linked installs)
- `DefaultInstance=` adds a symlink with a default name for instanced units (e.g. `multi-user.target.wants/foobar@default.service` -> `foobar@.service`)

However, unless your mounted filesystem is for a completely different architecture, you probably don't have to manually create these. `systemctl` works just fine for installing/uninstalling unit files even if `systemd` isn't currently running, so you should have no issues using `systemctl enable` and `disable` (use `chroot` to run in the correct directory root); obviously you don't need to run `daemon-reload` as there's no daemon process! I use this method at the end of a Gentoo installation to add startup units like `systemd-networkd` and friends, and it has worked with no issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `systemctl enable` with the `--root` flag. That flag not only sets the root directory for unit search files, but also instructs `systemctl` to operate on the file system directly instead of communicating with the system daemon.