# How to see full log from systemctl status service?

Tags: logs, systemd

I check service status with `systemctl status service-name`.

By default, I see few rows only, so I add `-n50` to see more.

Sometimes, I want to see full log, from start. It could have 1000s of rows.
Now, I check it with `-n10000` but that doesn't look like neat solution.

Is there an option to check full systemd service log similar to `less` command?

Answer (score 1416, accepted):

Just use the `journalctl` command, as in:

```
journalctl -u service-name.service
```

Or, to see only log messages for the current boot:

```
journalctl -u service-name.service -b
```

For things named `<something>.service`, you can actually just use `<something>`, as in:

```
journalctl -u service-name
```

But for other sorts of units (sockets, targets, timers, etc), you need to be explicit.

In the above commands, the `-u` flag is short for `--unit`, and specifies the name of the unit in which you're interested.  `-b` is short for `--boot`, and restricts the output to only the current boot so that you don't see lots of older messages.  See the [journalctl man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html) for more information.

Comment: appending `--no-pager` will print full log, so you wont have to scroll

Comment: appending `-e` will start the log at the end removing the need to scroll, but without printing the entire log beforehand.

Comment: appending `-f` will follow (print) updates to the log

Comment: appending `--help` will let you see all available options

Comment: are these logs being stored somewhere on the disk?

Comment: @viveksinghggits generally, although it depends on your configuration, but you still need to use `journalctl` to access them.

Comment: got it @larsks. `https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html`

Comment: Actually, this was not helpful for me - I want only the output since the unit was (re)started.  `sudo systemctl -n 99999 status` gives me that, but apparently journalctl can only filter "from boot", not "from service start".

Comment: I assume `--no-pager` will allow it to be piped? (say, to `grep`?)

Comment: `--no-pager` is not necessary when piping the output. It's only useful to disable the pager when output is to an interactive terminal. `journalctl` does not use a pager when you're piping the output to something else.

Comment: You can combine/append multiple units (`-u`) and thus combine the log of multiple services.

Comment: You can use `shift-g` to jump to the end of file in `less` or similar pagers.

Comment: Appending `-o cat` will remove systemd log text processing so you can see the output as the process produced it.

Comment: NB: do NOT use `journalctl UNIT=foobar.service` thinking like me that it's the same as `journalctl -u foobar.service`, because it's not! With `UNIT=` sudo commands coming from a custom script are not listed; they are displayed with `-u`.

Comment: whatever options I choose, I get `-- No entries --`

Comment: I really don't know why the message that tells you to check journalctl for more information doesn't tell you to do this - you know, the thing that will actually check for more information. It's so insane.

Answer (score 78):

`systemctl` can include the complete output of its status listing, without truncation., by adding the `-l` flag:

```
systemctl -l status service-name
```

`-l`: don't truncate entries with ellipses (...)

`--no-pager` can be added to avoid invoking a pager when the output is an interactive terminal.

Comment: Could you explicit your answer somehow? Adding some explanation about the options, and don't hesitate to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your answer!

Comment: This answer is wrong. The output stays truncated.

Comment: might not be best for current one, but gods... it will make my life easier going forward :D

Comment: Since this no longer works on my system, I've posted [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673548/353063) that makes it posible to get the full logs via `systemctl` (with full support to journalctl's options to boot). It's a hack but it's been working great for me so far.

Answer (score 44):

> #### Use `journalctl` to View Your System's Logs
>
> ︙
>
> **View `journalctl` without Paging**
>
> To send your logs to standard output and avoid paging them, use the
> `--no-pager` option:
>
> ```bash
> journalctl --no-pager
> ```
>
> It’s not recommended that you do this without first filtering down the
> number of logs shown.
>
> ```bash
> journalctl -u service-name.service
> ```
>
> ︙
>
> **Show Logs within a Time Range**
>
> Use the `--since` option to show logs after a specified date and time:
>
> ```bash
> journalctl --since "2018-08-30 14:10:10"
> ```
>
> Use the `--until` option to show logs up to a specified date and time:
>
> ```bash
> journalctl --until "2018-09-02 12:05:50"
> ```
>
> Combine these to show logs between the two times:
>
> ```bash
> journalctl --since "2018-08-30 14:10:10" --until "2018-09-02 12:05:50"
> ```

The above was largely copied
from [Use journalctl to View Your System's Logs](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-use-journalctl) at Linode Docs. 
There is more information available there.

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart: Please pay more attention to what you are doing.  `PagingPermalink` and `RangePermalink` are not code / command / keywords.  champion-runner blindly copied from the source document and somehow converted some non-textual links into the word “Permalink”.  Your edit nearly set his error in concrete.

Comment: In that case, apologies, @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'. However, what do those terms refer to, then? That's very unusual standard English, if it is so.

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart: Apology accepted.   /    Look at [the linked page](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-use-journalctl "Use journalctl to View Your System's Logs") and search for “To send your logs to standard output”.  It’s under a heading, “View journalctl without Paging  #”.  The “#” is a link to “https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-use-journalctl/#view-journalctl-without-paging”, i.e., a direct link to that section.  All the headings have direct links like that.

Comment: OK, “Permalink” is, obviously, short for “Permanent link”.  It’s a somewhat common web term.  For example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/552945 is a direct link to champion-runner’s answer, which we both edited.  It will take you to the (then) current state of the answer and its comments.  But https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/552945/1 is a ***permanent** link* to the first draft/revision of the answer — what it looked like before you edited it.  In other words, a link that is expected to work in the future to get to the exact same place it goes to today. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …   Now, I don’t understand why linode.com uses the term “permalink” to refer to what I would call a “direct link”, but, apparently, they do.     /     So, to repeat what I said yesterday, champion-runner somehow copied “Paging  #” and pasted “PagingPermalink”.

Comment: "PagingPermalink" is not standard English, although if I codified "Permalink", that was an accident. Thanks for the elaboration.

Answer (score 40):

Most of the time, it is convenient and easy to use the following `bash` command:

```bash
journalctl -xefu service-name.service
```

or

```bash
journalctl -xefu service-name
```

It works as if the process is executed via shell and the output is changing dynamically (similar to `tail -f`).

Comment: This is the only answer that shows if a unit has been started or stopped (or likewise restart).

Answer (score 17):

Using `journalctl`, write logs to a text file, and read it bottom up:

```bash
journalctl -u service-name.service > file_name.txt &&\
tail file_name.txt
```

Comment: Which `tail` command supports option `-r`, and what does it do?

Comment: I like this answer the best. Was able to quickly get real-time log output to a file that I could then winscp to snag it from a Windows box.

Comment: If you must use tail like this, at least skip the creation of a file and use pipes instead: `journalctl -u service-name.service | tail`. Better yet, skip tail and run `journalctl -eu service-name.service`.

Answer (score 7):

Since [@Julien's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419304/353063) no longer appears to work on my system (Debian 11), I've finally given in and hijacked `systemctl` on my system:

```bash
systemctl() { 
    if [[ "${1-}" == "log" ]]; then  
        /usr/bin/journalctl -u "${@:2}"; 
    else /usr/bin/systemctl "$@";
    fi 
}
```

Add this one-liner to your `.bashrc` and your `systemctl` will gain a new `log` "verb" that provides the missing functionality. No more wasting time retyping tedious commands.

As an added bonus, this method will also give you access to all the options of `journalctl` (provided that they're specified after the unit name):

```bash
systemctl log named.service --since=today
```