# How can I see previous logs with systemd?

Tags: systemd

I have a user unit running, that is currently failing. I want to know when it started failed, so I'm [checking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225407/18887) its logs with

```
journalctl --user -u pycardsyncer.service
```

However, this is only giving me the logs from the last four hours. Is there a way to get logs from prior to this?

Further, I sometimes see logs with the following:

```
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Where have these been "rotated" to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to `man journalctl` `journalctl` reads in journal files as created by `systemd-journald.service`.

According to `man systemd-journald.service` the config file is located at `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and it places journal files at `/var/log/journal/[machine-id]/*.journal` if it exists, otherwise it places them in `/run/log/journal/[machine-id]/*.journal`.

Those seem like the relevant files to you. On my machine the journal files were located in `/run/log/journal/[machine-id]/*.journal`

If the log files are being rotated too often it's possible that the `SystemMaxUse` or `RuntimeMaxUse` are too low in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. `journald` will rotate the file once it reaches the size defined here. Even if it's in the default state the default size is based on your hard drive capacity and can be problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had some files at `/var/log/journal/[machine-id]/*.journal`, but they only contained the data as per my question; they didn't go back further than that. (I had nothing at `/run/log/journal`.) FWIW my `uptime` is 3 days, but these logs seem to go back only ~5 hours.

Comment: @Sparhawk did you take a look in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` to see what's configured?

Comment: @Dave4 Yes, I did. I'm running Arch, so it's basically [as default](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/1c5ed0e2b4923b12be52c9c3e8f43682403dcf32/src/journal/journald.conf). There's no reference to any path at all, but there *are* recent logs in the directory you named (as per my first comment), so I figured that must be correct… just truncated.

Comment: @Sparhawk is the file that's kept always the same size? It may be that it is getting too large for the default `SystemMaxUse` or `RuntimeMaxUse`. If that happens the default values will still cause it to be rotated. What is the size of your HD?

Comment: Ahhh! Yes, sorry. The one thing that I did change from default was to limit how much disk space it used with `SystemMaxUse=50M`. Indeed, `/var/log/journal/[machine-id]` contains 69M. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you add this information to your answer, I'll accept it. (Please reply here when you've done it.) Cheers!

Comment: @Sparhawk added the info to the answer