# How to see the latest x lines from systemctl service log

Tags: systemd, journalctl, systemctl

I'm looking for a way, to simply print the last X lines from a systemctl service in Debian. I would like to install this code into a script, which uses the printed and latest log entries. I've found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225401/how-to-see-full-log-from-systemctl-status-service) post but I wasn't able to modify it for my purposes.

Currently I'm using this code, which is just giving me a small snippet of the log files:

```
journalctl --unit=my.service --since "1 hour ago" -p err
```

To give an example of what the result should look like, simply type in the command above for any service and scroll until the end of the log. Then copy the last 300 lines starting from the bottom.

My idea is to use egrep ex. `egrep -m 700 .` but I had no luck since now.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

```
journalctl --unit=my.service -n 100 --no-pager
```

Comment: "-n 100" means 100 lines ~for starters

Comment: add -q to suppress any hints by journalctl

Answer (score 46):

If you want to see the last *n* number of lines **and** see new messages as they are printed to the log, try this:

```
journalctl -u <service name> -n <number of lines> -f
```

Where `-n` indicates the number of lines you'd like to see from the tail of the log, and `-f` specifies that you'd like to follow the log as it changes.

Answer (score 33):

Just:

```
journalctl -u SERVICE_NAME -e
```

Parameter `-e` stands for:

> -e --pagerend; Immediately jump to the end of the journal inside the implied pager tool. This implies -n 1000 to guarantee that the pager
>   will not buffer logs of unbounded size. This may be overridden with an
>   explicit -n with some other numeric value, while -nall will disable
>   this cap.

Comment: That's the one ! Other answers will go through the whole log to get to its end, which can be veeeeery long for large syslogs.

Comment: Note `-e` is an alias for `--pager-end` (for people like me that have trouble remembering abbreviations)

Answer (score 16):

You could pipe the output to `tail`:

```
journalctl --unit=my.service | tail -n 300
```

The `tail` command prints the last lines (10 by default) received in stdin to stdout.

Edit: as noted in the comments, this is inefficient for very large logs.

Comment: Totally forgot about tail - great idea, thank you very much!

Comment: Tail can be painfully slow for large logs. The built-in `-n` of journalctrl is what you want. e.g. `journalctl -n 300`

Comment: A singularly bad idea.  Why would you pipe 30 terabytes of data into tail to show the last 10 records?

Comment: This is an especially bad answer. Don't do this!

Comment: @Drakes It's journalctl that's slow, not tail. `time journalctl > logs.txt; ls -sh logs.txt; time cat logs.txt | tail -1` on my system shows that systemctl takes 81 seconds to produce 647MB of logs, and tail takes about 0.4s to get the last line. Tail directly on the text file (like we used to do before binary logs) uses further optimizations and takes just 1 millisecond. `journalctl` is just glacial.

Comment: @marcelm this is inefficient regardless of the speed of `journalctl`; just use `journalctl -n 300` to get the last 300 lines rather than getting ALL the logs to then throw everything away except the last 300 lines.

Answer (score 0):

since tail command solution aleady provided.I tried by using sed commmand  and its worked fine

Below command will display last 300 lines

```
journalctl --unit=my.service | sed -e :a -e '$q;N;301,$D;ba'
```

Comment: That’s an interesting answer because: it shows what you can do with "sed", but it’s unhelpful for this question because: it’s *extraordinarily* less efficient than asking "journalctl" for the last ‘n’ lines directly. And it’s more verbose than using "tail". And the "sed" command is left unexplained—and without explanation, it is incomprehensible! But you’ve reminded me that I really should read up on "sed" some time!