# How to permanently remove eth0.x in CentOS

Tags: networking, network-interface, ethernet, ifconfig

I'm trying to remove eth0.x and keep eth0. While `ifconfig` lists both eth0.1 and eth0.500, I didn't find their configuration files `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.x`.

I tried `ifconfig eth0.1 down` and it worked.  But after restarting the network, both eth0.1 and eth0.500 came back.

Is there a way to permanently remove these two interfaces?

Comment: You can remove the network card from the machine (but note that then the `eth*` name can change on the next boot).

Comment: eth0.x and eth0 are on the same card.  Is there a way to remove eth0.x without deleting eth0? @grochmal

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking you use Centos 7, where Network-Manager is default network configuration utility. Two interfaces eth0.1 and eth0.500 are vlan 1 and vlan 500 tagged.
To show all interfaces use command: `# nmcli connection show`
To delete both vlan interfaces use these commands: 
`# nmcli con del eth0.1` and `# nmcli con del eth0.500`
You can find help there  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Configure_802_1Q_VLAN_Tagging_Using_the_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html

Answer (score 1):

These are virtual devices, they do not have their own configuration files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` but are defined in the main configuration file, something along the lines of this:

```
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.4.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

You can delete the interface using `ip link delete eth0.1` assuming you want to delete interface `eth0.1`. But if the main configuration file holds those lines or something similar as I wrote above then I think the interface will come back on reboot. To permanently remove it then find the lines that define the virtual interface and comment them out or remove them (I recommend commenting out, never know unless you need them some time again).

Comment: That `iface eth0:1` stuff looks like it's from Debian, and not what the RedHat `ifup-aliases` script looks for.

Comment: Which configuration file?  I didn't find the keyword "eth0:1" or "eth0.1" in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`

Comment: Ok, so this is different in Red Hat based distros, well unfortunately I am not that familiar with them. But somewhere in that system these virtual devices are defined, and the `ip` command should delete it just not permanently I guess.

Comment: Is there any mention of either `eth0.1` or `eth0.500` in one of the startup scripts in `/etc/rc.d/`? Something along the line of `ip link add eth0.1`. If so then comment that line out.

Comment: Or if you are in CentOS 7 then you are probably using systemd, then you need to look through startup scripts in `/etc/systemd/system/`. See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd) answer for a good explanation of how systemd startup scripts work.

Comment: @ojs I didn't find "eth0.x" in `/etc/rc.d/` using `grep -R "eth0" /etc/rc.d/*`.  The OS is CentOS 6.8, so there isn't a directory named `/etc/systemd/`

Comment: On Fedora24, I had a dummy bridge NIC device `br0-nic` left over, even after disabling and removing the `br0` bridge. `ip link delete br0-nic` was the only thing that worked for me. +1

Answer (score 1):

Before deleting the interface, just edit the file and set `onboot=no` then delete the interface with the command: `ip link delete eth0.1 and eth0.500`