# Netplan doesn't create default route

Tags: ubuntu, routing, netplan, ovh

OVH cloud host allows an easy way to route multiple blocks of their IPs to virtual MACs on one interface. For example, `eth0` has an address on the `40.30.20.0/24` network with a gateway of `40.30.20.254`, but their router is setup to also route traffic for `45.35.25.15/32` to that same interface. My VM's are macvtap'd off the host interface, with this virtual MAC assigned. When I try to setup netplan, I use this config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses:
        - 45.35.25.15/32
      gateway4: 40.30.20.254
    nameservers:
      addresses: [213.186.33.99]
```

Normally, that `gateway4` piece should give me a default route, but since it's outside the subnet, it barfs. I can't find a specific error in the logs. After applying netplan, and even rebooting, my `route` command is blank (no routes at all). `ifconfig` shows the interface is up and configured, just no routes. It's the only interface on the VM (besides `lo`), and all it takes to fix it is `sudo ip route add default dev ens3`, so why can't netplan just add such an obvious route to the only interface?? [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1764957) seems related, but never got addressed.

How do I use netplan to get a default route in this scenario?

Comment: oh, I guess in the linked bug the different subnet was a typo, whereas in my case it's legitimate...

Comment: For now I just made a startup script to add the route - for anyone following along, see this answer for instructions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd